# Upgrade Zimbra Server from 5.0.23 to 6.0.6.1

Tags: centos, zimbra

What are the most important points when upgrading a Zimbra server? Is there an upgrade guide?
Zimbra is running on a CentOS5 server. For now I think about the following steps:

- Backup Zimbra
- Stop all services
- Install new version

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade Zimbra 5.0.11 on Debian Etch to Zimbra 6.0.6 on Debian Lenny. There were many problems, but in a nutshell:

Upgrade started with install.sh wants Perl 5.10, but with this version ended on Perl error in the very beginning. The key is to downgrade perl to 5.8, which was in Debian Etch. Then start install.sh, ignore whining about prerequisities and continue with upgrade. Somewhere in the middle of upgrade it fails again, and now is mandatory to return Perl back to 5.10 and start this script:

```
/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetup.pl
```

And upgrade finally ends up correctly. This was on Debian, I'm not sure how it will be on CentOS.

It drived me nuts, at least I had Zimbra in virtual machine, so snapshot-and-restore was very helpful.

This is very good source of informations: http://blog.ideaday.de/max/2010/04/migrating-to-zimbra-6/

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to set

```
$prevVersion = "5.0.12_GA_2789";
```

in `/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetup.pl`  (as a copy from an unsuccessful run)
and to overwrite this script right after installation from the core-package (by a simple cp in install.sh) in order to let the install finish, otherwise it would stop since it had no "prevVersion"!

I went towards 6.0.16.